# Is the Eclipse CDT Refactoring Project Dead?

Tags: refactoring, eclipse-cdt, automated-refactoring

I've been over to the [site](http://r2.ifs.hsr.ch/cdtrefactoring/) lately and nothing much seems to work (aside from the main page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is most of that project has been included in the [newly released CDT6.0](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn60#Refactoring) and also [back in the CDT5.0](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn50#Refactoring) (as mentioned, for the 5.0 part, in this [blog post](http://kapo-cpp.blogspot.com/2008/06/install-eclipse-ganymede-rc2-with-cdt.html)).

[image]

Comment: Extract local variable? That's it?  No extract method?

Comment: Oh woopse, looks like they added the rest of that already...in 5.0 RC2.